# Proving that if $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ is normal, then the minimal polynomial of $T$ has no repeated roots.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

*Suppose $V$ is an inner-product space. Prove that if $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ is normal, then the minimal polynomial of $T$ has no repeated roots.*

Does anyone know how to prove this for the case where $V$ is a real inner-product space? Proving it for a complex vector space is pretty easy using facts about normal operators but the same arguments don't apply for real inner-product spaces.

Comment: I can post my proof for the case where $V \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$, if needed.

Comment: The minimal polynomial does not change through field extensions. You could view $V$ as a vector space over the complex numbers and apply your argument to conclude that the minimal polynomial of $T$ over $\mathbb{C}$ has no repeated factors. But the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are the same since $T$ is a real operator. See this [article](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/potdiagonalizable.pdf) by Keith Conrad for example.